# Traffic Volume/flow prediction Method

Tags: city, machine-learning, traffic

i have traffic volume data (surrey city, ca) like this
[image: the data are arterial traffic volume count from february 2013- 2014 in surrey]

I wish to use Artificial neural network (Deep Learning) or ARIMA to predict traffic flow/volume of the urban area with the use of previous traffic count data. I want to know whether it is a good technique to predict traffic condition, I want to make the data 2013 as training set and the data 2014 as a testing, is it possible to do traffic flow/volume prediction in next time period if only use this dataset or we need other data to support it?

did i choose right method? or which method is suitable for this case
i really appreciate if somebody could help me how to do that.. need guidance, i am new in neural network..

Comment: This site is about data, not about how to use it for prediction. Your question sounds like Business Intelligence, which officially on-topic (even though not very active) on http://dba.stackexchange.com Other sites might fit better. If not, the last desperate option would be https://www.reddit.com/r/artificial/